# how to extract the number only from a stringified array

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a super field that I want to convert from `[{"int":5},{"int":8}]` to `[5,8]`. How do I do this?

My query:

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'ethnicity', 'array') as ethnicity,
    ...
    FROM <table>
```

This query returns `[{"int":5},{"int":8}]`. Is there an elegant to return `[5,8]` in a super field?